# writing bytes to a file vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Why doesn't this code works ? :( , want to read from a binary file, then load the bytes to bitarray, then perform changes to bit array, then copy changes to the byte array then write changes to the file using the byte array. I'll provide commentary in the code.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    'Want to read from the binary file
    Dim array() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes("E:\binfile.bin")

    'to create the bit array   
    Dim ba1 As BitArray = New BitArray(8)

    ba1 = New BitArray(array)

    'want to set 1st bit to false (ie:0)
    ba1.Set(0, False)

    'want to set the changes made to bit array to binary array
    array.SetValue(ba1(0), 0)

    'want to save the binary file using binarywriter
    File.WriteAllBytes("E:\binfile.bin", array)
End Sub
```

Comment: The exception you get is an obvious reason for "it does not work".  Use ba1.CopyTo(array, 0) instead.

Comment: You initialize ba1 twice. ba1(0) will return true/false which you then set with SetValue. You should set the whole byte, not just a boolean.

Comment: If you are just changing that one bit, I would suggest you read up on Bitwise operators. It would reduce the complexity of your code.

Comment: @ Hans passant, OMG, it works .. when I use .CopyTo .... Thanks a lot .. how do I add reputation to you ?

Comment: @ the_lotus, I'll look into the bitwise operations :) many thanks.